# Javascript replace seem not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I think it's just a stupid mistake in my code, but I cant find it. Could you help me?

```
content = content.replace(/\[\[Kategoria:Dystrykty stanu Tamil Nadu‎/gi, "[[Kategoria:Dystrykty stanu Tamilnadu‎");
```

seem not to work properly.

```
[[Kategoria:Dystrykty stanu Tamil Nadu]] -> [[Kategoria:Dystrykty stanu Tamil Nadu]]
```

should be:

```
[[Kategoria:Dystrykty stanu Tamil Nadu]] -> [[Kategoria:Dystrykty stanu Tamilnadu]]
```

It seems to me that regexp is wrong, but I can't tell where and why. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an invisible character behind `Nadu` in the first part of your regex. Remove `Nadu‎/gi` and retype it again and it should work.

Edit: The invisible character is the [left-to-right-mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark). It is behind the replace-string too.